# Finding Prime Factors of a number in $\log(n)$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, computational-mathematics, sieve-theory

Only Strategy I am aware of for finding factors efficiently is sieve of eratosthenes but from sieve I first have to pre-compute the prime numbers less than than $\sqrt{n}$. I want to skip this computation and implement an $O(\log(n))$ solution. 
Is there any such solution?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fast_deterministic_tests) mentions a couple of tests of order $O((\log n)^k)$ for relatively low values of $k$, but none of order $O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

No. As determining whether a number $n$ is prime is in $O(n)$, finding a prime factor is obviously also in $O(n)$.

Comment: Even the most naive primality testing of a number $n$ is $O(\sqrt{n}(\log n)^2)$, since you have to check numbers up to and including $\sqrt n$ whether $n$ is divisible by any of them, and division is a $(\log n)^2$ operation. The most naive prime factoring has an additional factor $\log n$ ($n$ has up to $\log n$ factors, so you need to repeat the naive primality checking $\log n$ times to factor completely). I think you're confusing the size of a number with its number of digits. Number of digits would be the usual measure to use for computational complexity, but it's not used here.

Comment: Right, I didn't read the question carefully enough to see that $n$ was used in another way to what I expected. While the AKS test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) that I was thinking of does indeed run in the required time, it only (as far as I have understood) tells whether the number is prime, not what it's factors are. I don' know if (but I don't think so) any of the improvements does that, so this probably remains an open question.